# Running python function in ansible

Tags: python, python-2.7, ansible, ansible-2.x

python script test.py:

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        pass



    def addition(self, a, b):
        return a + b
```

Below is the ansible playbook to execute Python script.

```
---
- name: execute install script
  script: test.py
```

Instead of calling complete python script, Is it possible to  call only addition method in test.py  during ansible playbook execution

Answer (score 1):

I do not think that this is possible. If `test.py` contains many classes, you can do the following, which will only define one class and never instanciate it.

```
from test import Test
print(Test.addition(None, 3, 4)) # prints 7
```

Why putting your function as a class method if you want to import it alone though ?

You could also do the following:

test.py

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self):
       pass

# Define function outside class so that it can be imported
def addition(self, a, b):
    return a + b

# Add function to class
Test.addition = addition
```

And then do `from test import addition`

Comment: Yes I have same idea, if ansible does not support calling python function. Thanks you pointing function has to be defined separately